# DLL crashes app after reuse

Tags: c++, c, winapi, dll, crash

I use an application that uses mdi and a script can be attached to, and detached from, a mdi window to be run/stopped on demand; this script loads my dll that does some work; it does fine so; however, when I detach the script still all is fine and the application should unload the dll (and it calls dllmain with the appropriate thread_attach/detach and process_attach/detach operations). Now if I try to re-attach the script to the winow, or to attach it to another window, after the dll has been in use once - the main application crashes. I have isloated the problem to a thread that is created by the dll; the tread crates a window; so, I create the thread like so:

```
if (!hThread) hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadProc, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

and, when the script is detached it shuts down the thread like so (no matter if the commented-out lines are uncommented-out):

```
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_DESTROY, 0, 0);
//TerminateThread(hThread, 0);
//WaitForSingleObject(hWndThread, INFINITE);
CloseHandle(hThread);
hThread = NULL;
```

I'm at a loss here as to why the main app crashes. A different thread (i.e. one that would simply sleep for a second and loop, will do no harm. What gives?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/09/26/10216420.aspx

Comment: @Hans Passant  Thank you for looking at my problem. Unfortunatley sending WM_CLOSE or calling DestroyWindow does not solve the problem.

Comment: Well, all we know that you were doing it wrong but we still don't know what the crash looks like.  Post at least the crash reason and the content of the call stack.  Also look in the Output window for any first chance exception notifications.

Comment: @Hans  I do not have control over the host application; all I contribute is the script and the DLL that it uses. Since the application crashes there is no feedback :D  As far as I know I am destroying all data that I am supposed to destroy. No clue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here are some ideas:
You said your thread opens a window. Do you run a message loop in the thread function, or you expect your window to be serviced by some other message loop?
If you are running your own message loop in the thread, then exiting the loop may or may not happen, depending on how you have written it. If you use something like:

```
while(GetMessage(&msg, ...) // msg loop in the thread function
{
  .... 
}
DestroyWindow(hWnd);  // see comment below
```

then this requires a WM_QUIT and not WM_DESTROY to exit. Anyway, the best is to send your window a WM_QUIT and after exiting the message loop then call DestroyWindow() to destroy it properly.
Quoting from MSDN:

> **DestroyWindow function**
>   Destroys the specified window. The function sends WM_DESTROY and WM_NCDESTROY messages to the window to deactivate it and remove the keyboard focus from it. The function also destroys the window's menu, flushes the thread message queue, destroys timers, removes clipboard ownership, and breaks the clipboard viewer chain (if the window is at the top of the viewer chain

After posting WM_QUIT message to your window, your main thread should wait for the window thread to exit. Here is some relevant code:

```
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);  // send your quit message to exit the msg loop
if (WaitForSingleObject(hThread, 5000) != WAIT_OBJECT_0) // wait up to 5 seconds
{
    TerminateThread(hThread, -1); // bad! try to never end here
}
```

I hope this helps. I use this in a threaded log viewer that uses a window to display log messages.

Comment: EDIT: 'After destroying your window' should read : 'After posting WM_QUIT message to your window.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.
I do run a message loop. However, usually I close the window manually (via close button), therefore the window would receive wm_quit via postquitmessage.
Nevertheless I do an extra sendmessage with wm_close message.
I think I have tried all the combinations but still no luck.
Anyway, it is not a pressing problem anymore because now the code works; it was a hassel only while debugging/designin it, because each time I had to change the code I also had to restart the hosting application (that itself had to re-connect to a remote server).
Anyway, thanks again.